ADC pin protection when using external power supply
I was playing with ADC on ESP32-C6 (devkit board) trying to read values from photoresistor (VT90N2) in voltage divider with another (10K) resistor.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
ESP32-C6 was connected to a PC via USB (to upload firmware and watch logs) UPD2: so it was powered by the PC, voltage divider was powered by an external power supply (UNI-T UTP1306) simultaneously. The power supply has "enable" button, so one could set voltage and current when it's turned on, and then press "enable" button to actually put voltage on the outputs.
When I wanted to make changes to a firmware, I've changed the code, built my project, toggled off "enable" button on the power supply, uploaded the firmware to the mcu via USB, then toggled on "enable" button, watching logs from ADC. At some point (I believe after another toggle on) the mcu became irresponsive. I tried to power the mcu with external power supply and mcu looked like a short circuit, because current consumption was limited by power supply. Increasing the limit did nothing, because current consumption increased to the limit again.

What protective measures (in schematics) should I've taken to prevent damage of the mcu (UPD1: when using external power supply)?
What is the physics behind the process which could damage the mcu in such a set up?
Does 5-10K resistance to ADC just slows down the readings or does it also impacts on accuracy of measurements?


It's very unlikely that a spike on the ADC pin caused damage. The resistor and internal clamp diodes limit any excessive voltage to the supply voltage.
If you are using the same power supply to power up the ESP32, then the spike in the voltage can damage the module.
To answer your questions:

To protect an input, you can use a circuit like this (image source):


Read the rest of that post. There are good explanations about how to use TVS.
You can have a TVS on the power rail to absorb any surge (source of image):


Every semiconductor has a limit on the voltage it can hold without breaking. That surge could exceed that voltage and unwanted current will flow throw the semiconductor. This can be a transistor that is in the off-state or a reverse-biased diode. That current is what damages the chip.

If by slow down, you mean delay (lag), no. The resistor divider does not slow down the signal. However, if you use the capacitor like the first image I added, then yes. That is a low pass filter and it has a delay. The time constant of the filter is RC.


About accuracy, you don't lose it because of the resistor itself. You only lose the accuracy only if you don't use the whole span of the ADC input range. If the potentiometer allows the voltage to reach 3V, then you are measuring as accurately as it can be.
Just a quick note: The ADC on ESP32 is not very good. The error around 0 and around 3V is high and non-linear. Also, the input bias current on ADC pins is high. You probably need to buffer your signal using an op amp to get a better result.


Why to use low pass filter? Is it also a protective measure or to filter out high frequency noise on the ADC input? 2. I understand the existence of limits in semiconductors, but don't understand where this surges come from? As you said: "It's very unlikely that a spike on the ADC pin caused damage", does the spike depends on the circuit after power supply or on the power supply itself? What determines whether it's spike or not? 3. By slow-down I meant that ADC probably has capturing capacitor inside and "big" divider (output) resistance should increase $\tau_{RC}$?


The filter removes high-frequency noise. The spike is usually high frequency too. The surge could come from a bad power supply design. It's a guest. You need to connect an oscilloscope and check for transient on power ON. For slow down, yes; a big resistor will create a bigger time constant. However, the input capacitance is usually too low to consider here.

In theory there is nothing wrong with the setup, but also the moment of enabling the supply may have overshoots or other spikes in the voltage when it suddenly turns on the output.
Most microcontrollers have input protection diodes and can generally clamp a few mA without problems, however, in your setup the 20k variable resistor is used as a 2 terminal resitor so if it was set to extreme end of 0 ohms then there is no series resistance to limit the current.

A series resitor maybe. Or you could have used the 3.3V supply pin of the ESP board.

Overvoltage/overcurrent on MCU pin will damage it. Too high voltage arcs over the internal semiconductor structures and too high current on thin wires and semiconductor structures make them heat up and burn like a fuse.

Depends on ADC specs but generally 5k to 10k of source impedance into ADC input is low enough.



Thank you for the answer. I'd like to understand the nature of the overvoltage/overcurrent, where does it come from, why does it happen, how to protect against it? I'd like to know it to see potential problems with other circuits in the future. Googling didn't give me answers on this. Are there any google queries you could advise? Are there any possible problems if restarting the mcu during the power supply is enabled?

@valeroso Good question. When your power supply is turned on, can you guarantee the voltage rises to 3.3V so there is no excessive peaking, and does it rise slowly or abruptly, and does your wires have stray capacitances or inductances so a step pulse from 0V to 3.3V causes overshoot and ringing. But mainly it boils down if you trust the lab supply output when output is enabled, or will it be better to enable output and then connect wires.
